# IE only loads remotely hosted .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, highcharts, local

I'm testing a very simple application with highcharts using their demo code.

When I load the demo in FF it works.  When I load the demo in IE it does not, unless I use the remotely hosted jquery.min.js file and highcharts.js file.

I have the jquery file and highcharts.js saved on my domain.  They are both able to be used correctly in FF.  When I load the page in IE, however, I get no output, unless I use the other ones.

The files I have on my server are the same.  THey obviously work (in FF) but for some reason IE does not like them.

To clarify, when I do this:

```
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/highcharts.hs"></script>
```

it works in FF but not in IE.

When I do this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

It works in FF and also IE.

I have subsittuted them out one at a time and it only works in IE if both of them are the latter version.

Why does IE does not want to run the .js files if I load them on my own domain rather than loading the ones that are hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Which errors do you have in console? Why you use highcharts.hs, instead of js ?

Answer (score 1):

First things first you've got the wrong extension for your highcharts JavaScript file. It should be `/highcharts.js` and not `/highcharts.**hs**`

For your own domain the absolute URL is not needed.

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Make sure you download that script content for the googleapis.com and highcharts.

If you're testing in a local environment the `http://www.mydoman.com/` is worthless.

Do you not have a scripts folder? If so the src URL would look like

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: I mistyped the extension.

The version of the scripts I'm using is correct because it works correctly in Firefox.  The problem seems to occur when I try to load the site in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.

I had added the following code to .htaccess to prevent other sites from using my .js:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

This code prevented my own .js from being used in IE, but not in FF.  Do different browsers treat the file differently?

When I removed that code from my .htaccess file, the website loaded as expected in both FF and IE.

That also explains why my .css wasn't working unless I loaded it from an external source (I was using a js accordian which has its own css).  I got that code from another post on this site and tested it in FF and assumed it would work in IE as well.  Now I'm going to need to get new .htaccess code that is IE friendly as well.